# Access to raw binary float data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm receiving IEEE754 32-bit floating point data from a remote system and storing it in a MySQL (MariaDB) database. I'm trying to ensure that I can retrieve the data from the database exactly as it was received, so ideally I would be able to insert the binary data directly (to avoid any rounding errors).

Since MySQL uses IEEE754 for floats, I'm wondering if there is any way to work with the binary data directly, or do I have to store data as binary data and convert it outside of MySQL (or store two copies of the data, one in a binary column and one as float column)?

Comment: If you use prepared statements, the data is sent in binary, and I think it will be sent exactly,.

Comment: I think you are correct, thanks!

Comment: What client software are you using?  Many clients, plus MySQL, like to do virtually every thing in 64-bit floating point (`DOUBLE`).  Then, at the last minute, it is converted to 32-bit (`FLOAT`).  Is the remote system sending you 4-byte binary or 8-byte hex?